# Problems populating a file with PHP

Tags: php

Basically my problem is the next one... the following script connects a the DB and creates a file.... everything works fine.. except that when it populates the file.. it doesn't put the variables `$username`, `$password`, `$server` and `$dbname` into the file.
the created file looks like this

```
<?php

    // Database Constants
    $DB_SERVER ="";
    $DB_USER ="";
    $DB_PASS ="";
    $DB_NAME ="";
    ?>
```

but it should have something inside the quotes :S

my script is as follows

```
<?php 
//DB Config File
$dbFile = 'dbconfig.php';

function createfile ($dbFile) {
        //Creates File and populates it.
        $fOpen = fopen($dbFile, 'w');

            $fString .= "<?php\n";
            $fString .= "// Database Constants\n";
            $fString .= "\$DB_SERVER =" . "\"" . $server . "\";\n";
            $fString .= "\$DB_USER =" . "\"" . $username . "\";\n";
            $fString .= "\$DB_PASS =" . "\"" . $password . "\";\n";
            $fString .= "\$DB_NAME =". "\"" . $dbname . "\";\n";
            $fString .= "?>";

        fwrite($fOpen, $fString);
        fclose($fOpen);
return true;
}


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$server = $_POST['server'];
$dbname = $_POST['dbname'];


try {
$db = new PDO ('mysql:host=' .$server.';dbname='.$dbname,$username,$password);

if ($db) { //if succesful at connecting to the DB

if (file_exists($dbFile)){
    if (is_readable($dbFile) && is_writable($dbFile)){ 

        //Creates File, populates it and redirects the user

    if (createfile($dbFile)) { 
    header("Location: http://http://localhost/proj11/install2.php");
    exit ();
            }


        } else { 

        $msg = "2The file {$dbFile} cannot be accessed. Please configure the file manualy or grant Write and Read permission.";  }

    } else {

        //Creates File, populates it and redirects the user

    if (createfile($dbFile)) {

    header("Location: http://http://localhost/proj11/install2.php");
    exit ();
            }

        }


}

} catch (PDOException $e) { //Catchs error if can't connect to the db.
    $msg = 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="iForm" method="post" action="install.php">
<label id="username" >Username</label>
<input id="username" name="username"/>
<label id="password">Password</label>
<input id="password" name="password" />
<label id="server" >Server</label>
<input id="server" name="server"/>
<label id="dbName" >dbName</label>
<input id="dbName" name="dbname"/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<p id="error"><?php echo $msg ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW: `header("Location: http://http://localhost/proj11/install2.php");` doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert :

```
function createfile ($dbFile) {
        //Creates File and populates it.
```

to this :

```
function createfile ($dbFile) {
        global $username, $password, $server, $dbname; 
        //Creates File and populates it.
```

or this :

```
function createfile ($dbFile, $username, $password, $server, $dbname) {
        //Creates File and populates it.
```

naturaly in the last case your call become :

```
createfile ($dbFile, $username, $password, $server, $dbname);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variables `$username`, `$password`, ... are no global variables. They are not in the scope of the function. You need to pass those variables to the function.

Or use `global` keyword:

```
function createfile ($dbFile) {
  global $server;
  global $username;
  global $password;
  global $dbname;
  ...
```

But please mind, overusing `global` is very bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing `$server, $username, $password, $dbname` to the function.

Try doing

```
function createfile($dbfile,$params)
{
   list($server,$username,$password,$dbname) = $params;
   /* ... */
}

/* ... */

if (createfile($dbFile,array($server,$username,$pasword,$dbname)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to reference the global variables using the `global` keyword:

```
function createfile ($dbFile) {
    global $username, $password, $server, $dbname;
```

Or pass them to `createfile` explicitly:

```
function createfile ($dbFile, $username, $password, $server, $dbname) {

/* ... */

if (createfile($dbFile, $username, $password, $server, $dbname)) {
```